# Can Elasticsearch do a reverse prefix search?

Tags: elasticsearch

The normal [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) will find "kibana" when searching for "ki".

Is there a way to find "ki" when searching for "kibana"? I.e. match where the *field* is a prefix of the *query term*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying a [search analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) that includes ngram or [edgengram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) token filters

Comment: Would I be mistaken to assume this would be similar to issuing N queries, where N is the `max_gram` for edge n-gram?

Comment: Not really - the resulting tokens from analysing the search input will be compared to those tokens produced for the target field by analysis at index time.

Comment: The crucial part is that the search analyzer will perform ngramming, but the index analyzer won't.

Comment: Yeah. So the dabatase won't bloat, but search time should be affected linearly with `max_gram - min_gram`. Okay, thanks. Not sure that helps me, but it does answer my question.

Comment: Correct, the cost will be paid at search time by the complexity of analysis.